# How to find the peak 3D coordinate inside a list of 3D coordinates using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, 3d, directx

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;

struct Voxel
{
    public Vector3 p

    public Voxel(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        p = new Vector3(_x, _y, _z);
    }
}

List<Voxel> myDataList = new List<Voxel>();
```

After some add data method, then i finally get `myDataList` to have something like below:

```
myDataList[0] - { X: 164 , Y: 59 , Z: 120 }
myDataList[1] - { X: 146 , Y: 63 , Z: 120 }
myDataList[2] - { X: 192 , Y: 59 , Z: 120 }
myDataList[3] - { X: 196 , Y: 79 , Z: 120 } //peak coordinate is here
myDataList[4] - { X: 110 , Y: 55 , Z: 120 }
```

In the above example, myDataList[3] is the peak coordinate where it has the highest Y value, which is 79.

My question is, how can I get to identify that myDataList[3] is the peak coordinate where it contain the highest Y value?

I know I can do something like below to get the max Y value

```
float maxY = myDataList.Max(y => y.p.Y); //output = 79
```

But what I want is the 3D coordinate (X, Y, Z) instead of just knowing the `maxY`

***Do not order the list by descending w.r.t Y value and `.First()`, because the order of myDataList does matter in my next proceeding step.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you already have `maxY` you can use that value to find max `Voxel` like below

```
var maxVoxel = myDataList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.p.Y ==maxY);
```